# Transferred database between WooCommerce to Magento

Tags: database, magento, woocommerce

I have a database with multiple languages, so i transferred the database between WooCommerce to Magento. It's transferred only English language without other's. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the litextension service to migrate woo-commerce to Magento.
Below is the litextension migration extension of magento2:
https://marketplace.magento.com/litextension-woocommerce-to-magento-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a tool that transfers multiple languages across platforms. There's a bunch of solutions on the market that offer such services, but I'd suggest you try [Cart2Cart module](https://marketplace.magento.com/magneticone-cart2cart-migration-from-woocommerce.html). I've used it on a couple of my stores and it worked perfectly . Most importantly, there's no risk of damaging your store, since you'll just have to configure the migration and the system will migrate the data automatedly